# Ergodicity of the system in the Furstenberg's Correspondence Principle

Tags: ergodic-theory

In order to apply a theorem in the lecture my professor used the following lemma that states what follows:
One can assume without loss of generality that the system obtained in Frustenberg's Correspondence Principle is ergodic and has continuous eigenfunctions.

**Question**
He didn't give to us the proof of this Lemma, and I don't see why this is true! I was wondering how to prove it. Does somebody see how to prove it and has some hints?

I recall the Furstenberg's Correspondence Principle: For any $ A \subseteq \mathbb{N} $ there exists a compact metric space $X$, a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $X$, a continuous measure preserving transformation $T:X \to X$, a point $x \in X $ that is generic for $\mu$ along some sequence $(I_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ of intervals whose length dents to infinity, and a clopen set $E \subseteq X$ such that $\overline{d}(A) = \mu (E) $ and $A= \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : T^n x \in E \} $, where $\overline{d}(A)$ is the upper density of $A$.

Comment: Can you say what $\mu$ being generic along a sequence of intervals mean? Also by upper densite do you mean asymptotic density?

Comment: (Def.) A point $x \in X$ is called generic for $\mu$ if $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(T^n x) = \int f d\mu$ for every continous function. More generally, if $ (I_k)_{k} $ is a sequence of intervals in $ \mathbb{N} $ whose length dents to infinity (I suppose that is a typo and "dents" is "tends" so that the definition coincides with the choice of intervals $I_k = \{1,\ldots, k\}$), then $x$ is called generic for $ \mu$ along $(I_k)_k$ if $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{\left| I_k \right|} \sum_{n \in I_k} f(T^n x) = \int f d\mu $.

Comment: By upper density of a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N} $, I mean $ \overline{d}(A) = \lim \sup_{ N \to \infty} \frac{ \left| A \cap \{1,\ldots,N\} \right|}{N} $

Comment: @3m0o It's been a while, so are you still interested in the question?